# UWP blinking text

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

this might sounds very simple, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I just want a blinking text in TextBlock. Is there a way to do it easily?

The only way I can think of is to use timer and change the TextBlock foreground manually. Surely there is an easy way to do it. I am just not able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a storyboard that handles the blinking activity and use this storyboard indefinitely

Comment: Have you tried creating a `Storyboard` in the XAML that changes the foreground; starting it in the `Loaded` event of your UserControl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could declare a `Storyboard` animation in your XAML markup which blinks the text forever:

```
<TextBlock Text="I'm Blinking!">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimation" >
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

This is using my experience from WPF and WinRT XAML, but I'm pretty sure that UWP uses the same `Storyboard` animations.

Here's Microsoft's handy reference on MSDN: [Animations Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Geoff, you are the MAN!!! Thank you! I knew there must be something simple. I need to learn more about Storyboard. Thanks for sharing, champ!

Comment: In UWP, "the attachable property resources was not found in style"

Answer (score 6):

From code behind (C#) you can do it for example with code like this:

```
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
        DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 1.0,
            To = 0.0,
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0),
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, txtBlink);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, "Opacity");
        storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);
        storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        storyboard.AutoReverse = true;
        storyboard.Begin();
```

Assuming you have a textblock:

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlink" FontSize="32">Some text</TextBlock>
```

Comment: you might need to change the second argument of `SetTargetProperty() `to `new PropertyPath ("Opacity")` in order to convert string to PropertyPath

Answer (score 0):

For blinking text, I think timer is the easiest approach. (Though i understand you have the thought of using a timer & looking for an alternate, tier should actually serve the purpose)
Might be something like below can help you.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void Blinker()
    {            
        timer.Interval = 500;

        timer.Start();

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
    }

    void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green)
        {
            label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }

        else
        {
            label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }            
    }

    public void StopBlinker()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Now you can call the blinker method appropriately to make your text blink.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly my thought. But I like the concept of Storyboard. +1 for sharing :)